# Proof of Introduction to Calculus

Tags: calculus

I can’t find an answer to this:

-Show that for every rational  $r > 0$ there is a natural n such that
$r>\frac {n}{n^2+1}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r$ be an arbitrary positive real number.

Note that $$r>\frac {n}{n^2+1}$$ is equivalent to $$ \frac {n^2+1}{n} >\frac {1}{r}$$

$$ n+\frac {1}{n} >\frac {1}{r}$$

Since natural numbers are not bounded above there is a natural number $$n>
\frac {1}{r}$$

Thus $$n+\frac {1}{n} >n>\frac {1}{r}$$

Answer (score 0):

Choose any natural number $n\ge\frac{1}{r}$. This number will do the job! Indeed, $$r>\frac{n}{n^2+1}\implies\frac{1}{n}+n>\frac{1}{r}$$But $$n+\frac{1}{n}>n\ge\frac{1}{r}$$which clearly shows that $n$ is a useful candidate here!

Answer (score -1):

$n \ge 1;$

$\dfrac{n}{n^2+1} <\dfrac{n}{n^2}=\dfrac{1}{n}.$

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ s.t.

$n > \dfrac{1}{r}$.

Then

$\dfrac{n}{n^2+1} <\dfrac{1}{n} <r$.